# not all dlls appear in the release folder - therefor: "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a problem that when I move the release folder of the application to the destination server and run the application it says "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies".
I think I know where it comes from, but what I dont know is how to fix it.

In my program I use 4 external dlls AntiXSSLibrary, HtmlSanitizationLibrary, MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity. When I "add reference" in visual c# 2010 express and build the solution I can see in the bin/release folder only 2 dlls - AntiXSSLibrary and HtmlSanitizationLibrary(and their xml). The MySQL dlls dont appears there - one of them is the dll that shown on the exception error message - and I dont know why it doesnt copy them to there too. BTW if I copy them myself it doesnt help..

On my computer - where the program is been build - it runs ok.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

Another thing that caught my eye is on the last line of the stack "at ... Program.Main... IN C:\Users\AAA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010.....\Program.cs line 12"

WHY is it trying to access my build location + cs file where I'm it in my prod server and running the exe from different location..? you can see in the picture the hole thing:
[image]

Comment: The build paths come out of the program database (PBD) files - they are generated at compile-time, not from your actual execution path.

Comment: So is it ok/not ok? Should I remove the pbd file from the prod server?

Comment: The PDB files have no influence on how your code is actually running - only on how problems are reported.

Comment: Did you check you maybe those libraries (MySql.Data, etc.) are platform specific (x86 for example), but your release mode compiles x64 libaries, hence you cannot reference them.

Comment: All of them are installed under program file(x86) so I believe they are NOT platform specific..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AntiXSSLibrary and HtmlSanitizationLibrary were build as .net 2.0 and the mysql was 4.0. Since I dont have the AntiXSSLibrary and HtmlSanitizationLibrary in 4.0 I've putted the mysql 2.0 build. That fixed the problem.